# Smoothing a function discretely using line segments

Tags: geometry

I'm currently trying to use maths in a pathing issue. Let me try to explain it. 
[This is a path that is not smoothed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7XGb.png) and I would like to smooth it like the dashed line. I've tried a moving average filter, but it's not as good as I would like it to be.

Now someone suggested me using a line segment of constant length to smooth out the path. I've tried to draw it as well as I could. [The smoothed path is the red line that forms thanks to the lines connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjHC6.png)

The two orange dots are 200 units apart and the two green dots are also 200 units apart.

I was curious if there is mathematical way to generate the right combined path. And if not, if there is a programming way to generate the red path. Or even another place I could ask for a closer step towards a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up Bezier curves

Comment: If the angle between segments is right, then the curve is an astroid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)#Example_4

Comment: Did you try your method when the angle in the path is acute? I think there may be some problem in that case.